# How does static linking work with system files?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm a beginning C++ programmer and I'm trying to make a fully static program (just one .exe) in Visual Studio. It's gotten me thinking though, because there are some external dependencies that are pulled from the user's computer, like MSVCP.dll. Are those dependencies baked in to the program from the programmer's computer, or are they still left out and pulled from the user?

-Ari

Comment: There's an option to link with a static version of C runtime library (CRT), as opposed to a DLL version. If you do that, then yes, the CRT is baked into the executable.

Comment: The CRT can be statically linked. Although if the target audience is on windows 10 you probably  don't have to worry about shipping the runtime for VS2015 or greater.

Comment: So if you have the option to do either, what are the benefits to each option?

Comment: The benefit to static CRT is you don't have to ship the redistributable with your installer package. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

Comment: Executable size, mostly.  A simple hello world application comes out around 12KB if I dynamically link to the CRT and 219KB if I statically link it.

Comment: @drescherjm the downsides are that it could conflict with other libraries that included their own static CRT, and security because it wouldn't get patched via windows update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MS Visual C++ compiler gives you the option to choose what version of the MS Visual C/C++ Runtime library you want to link to.  The choices are:

- /MT - Statically link to the non-debug multithreaded version of the CRT.  This has the benefit of not requiring you to ship the CRT DLLs along with your application, which may be required for it to run on some systems otherwise.  The downside is that the CRT code used by your application has to be baked into your executable, increasing its size.  This is compounded if your application has multiple executables and DLLs, since a lot of the same CRT code will have to be baked into each of them.
- /MTd - Statically link the debug multithreaded version of the CRT.  Same as above, but the added debugging info will make it run slower and be even bigger.  Mainly useful for development builds.
- /MD - Dynamically link to the DLL of the non-debug multithreaded version of the CRT.  This can reduce the size of your program's executable.  This savings can be compounded if your application consists of multiple executables and DLLs, since they can share the same CRT code between them.  This may require you to ship the CRT DLLs or for your users to install them separately though, which can be extra hassle and complexity.
- /MDd - Dynamically link to the DLL of the debug multithreaded version of the CRT.  Same as above, but added debugging info will run slower.  Mainly useful for development builds.

Doing a quick test with a simple hello world program, the compiled executable ended up being about 12KB with /MD, while it weighed in at about 219KB with /MT, so the difference in size is considerable, especially if you're shipping lots of small programs.

---

There also used to be single-threaded versions of the library that could, in theory provide better single-thread performance and smaller size, but those are no longer provided with newer versions of the CRT.  Presumably the difference was too minor for it to make sense shipping an entire separate build of the library.

Comment: IIRC the single threaded versions just didn't include locks on things like IO. The standard now requires the stdlib to be thread safe in some areas so that would actually make it non-compliant.

Comment: Oh. I thought /MT meant you were linking your own program statically.
So just to get this straight, you use /MD to dynamically link to CRTs, and you can still statically link to your own program files and external libraries?
Also, if you dynamically link to CRTs, can you expect the user to already have them (like coming prepackaged with Windows)? Or must they come with the release build?

Comment: Right, you can use /MD and still statically link to some other library.  Be careful though.  That library must also have been built with /MD.  I think Windows 10 ships with a version of the CRT (for VS2015 and above, according to @drescherjm in the comments on the original question), but I've not kept up, so I don't know the details for sure (the last Windows app I shipped was built with VS2010 intended for WinXP and newer).

Answer (score 1):

> Are those dependencies baked in to the program from the programmer's computer, or are they still left out and pulled from the user?

As @Igor comments, you can do either. The difference being a (perhaps rather large) single independent statically-linked executable file or one that depends on local DLLs to run.

Comment: The other difference is security, using the dynamic CRT the CRT is patched via windows update. The static CRT is not and requires a relink with a patched version.